# Перемещение по DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

Здравствуйте, уважаемые ХэшКодеры!

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Есть ссылка. По клику, она меняется на `input type="text"`.
2. Вводим в `input` число.
3. После того, как ввели число и нажали на `Enter`, `input`, снова меняем на ссылку, но уже с числом введенным в `input`.
4. Далее, перемешаем данный блок, содержащий ссылку, согласно порядкового номера (предположим, что их десять) и выделяем этот блок другим цветом.

Что сделал я:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input id="num" type="text" />');
});
```

Вот собственно и все, что я смог сделать. Насколько я понимаю, необходимо сохранить введенное число, например так:

```
var save = $('#num').datach();
```

А вот как сделать все последующие действия, я не знаю. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Уважаемые ХэшКодеры, подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данную задачу, или хотя бы направьте в нужное русло.

Comment: Уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы при потере фокуса, все вернулось на свои исходные места. То есть, если было в ссылке, до изменения цифра 2, то чтобы в случае отмены или потери фокуса, 2 и осталась. 
Вот здесь можно посмотреть то, что сделано... http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/P5n4T/3/

Answer (score 1):

считаю, что здесь целесообразнее хранить сразу пару элементов: ссылка и поле ввода. в зависимости от этапа выполнения, они по очереди будут display:hidden, т.е. пока ссылку не нажали - инпут не виден, а если нажали - то ссылка хайдится а поле ввода показывается.
такую пару можно завернуть в блочный элемент с каким-то классом, и делать выборку по классу.

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотрите этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ZNTEg/1/). Не очень старался оптимизировать, т.к. в глазах уже "дули", но вроде как работает. Уверен, что можно придумать чего-то получше.

Comment: Уважаемый Deonis, спасибо большое, но к сожалению работает не корректно, а вернее, жутко глючит.